# Is there a name for a pattern that keeps remote UI elements synced based on model changes?

Tags: design-patterns

I want to research existing solutions for a particular software pattern that I believe must be very common in today's world of disconnected software. I'm not having any luck searching online for a way of describing it and am wondering if there is a way of describing the pattern that I'm not aware of.

The design that I'm looking for is desribed below:

I'm trying to design an (object-oriented) application where a number of remotely connected controls (UI elements) need to be redrawn as quickly as possible. I don't have a particular language or target in mind yet, but for the sake of argument, let's say each control is drawn on a Canvas element in a webpage. For any particular instance of this control, the look of is based on a fairly complicated data object (the model) that might have a few hundred thousand properties.

Because of the number of controls potentially in existence and because of the complexity of the data object, I'm going to synchronize each remote copy of the data object by sending patches over the wire (rather than sending the whole data object every time). I would then like to use the same patch/transformation data to re-draw only the parts of the control that need to be repainted.

For the patching mechanism, I'm imagining using something akin to an Operational Transformation for objects (rather than for plain-text). I'd then use the same patch information in the painting system to determine what parts of the control need to be repainted on any update.

I imagine that this is a very common scenario, and I don't want to totally re-build the wheel here (though I do understand the draw mechanism will depend on the specific drawing algorithms).

Is there some term of art for this kind of remote-object-syncing-and-painting mechanism that I can search online for? Is this a recognised pattern?

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding you are looking for `Observer` design pattern. `Observer` pattern is mostly used in many graphical user interface toolkits to separate the presentational aspects of the user interface from the underlying application data. Both a spreadsheet object and bar chart object can depict information in the same application data object using different presentations.

When the dependency relationship between subjects and observers is particularly complex, an object that maintains these relationships might be required. We call such an object a `ChangeManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more or less what React does (except for the ridiculousness of having a couple of hundred thousand properties).

It gives you server-side rendering that you can continue to work with on the client side. It offers partial updates using information from the state. And you can retrieve that state (partially) using GraphQL and update it locally.

It is going to require a whole lot of configuration and glue to make this work, but all of the foundational primitives are more or less in place.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution based on the Observer design pattern and Composite design pattern might be able to solve your problem.